# how to replace ’ with &#146; in perl

Tags: regex, perl

I have below piece of code in Perl

```
my $file2 = "devil’s-claw-extract.html";
$file2 =~ s/’/&#146;/ig;
print "$file2";
```

This code is working fine(means replacing ’ with `&#146;`) when running in konsole but not working in browser.

Please help me out.

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"?

Comment: That's because browser converts &#146 back to ’ when you print it.

Comment: What do you mean by `not working in browser`?  Isn't `&#146;` the HTML encoding for `'`?

Comment: Press `ctrl + u` to check the HTML-Sourcecode. your `&#146;` will be convertet into `'`

Answer (score 4):

Of course it “works”, and I will believe so until you produce a self-contained example that indicates otherwise.

Your first problem is that you are reinventing the wheel, there already is a [module on CPAN to do such escaping](https://metacpan.org/module/HTML%3a%3aEntities) for you:

```
use utf8; # because this source file contains special chars
use HTML::Entities;
my $file2 = "devil’s-claw-extract.html";
print encode_entities $file2;
```

Output:

```
devil&rsquo;s-claw-extract.html
```

or with `encode_entities_numeric`:

```
use utf8;
use HTML::Entities 'encode_entities_numeric';
my $file2 = "devil’s-claw-extract.html";
print encode_entities_numeric $file2;
```

Output:

```
devil&#x2019;s-claw-extract.html
```

Secondly, it is worth noting that your input string contains `’`, a single right quote. This has the codepoint `U+2019` (not `U+0092`, which is in a private use area. Conveniently, it decodes to `’` in the Windows-1252-encoding, but the actual encoding should always be explicitly set).

The *apostrophe* `'`, which you likely wanted, is `U+0027` or `&apos;`.

Comment: But after using use HTML::Entities ,its giving output as below   devilâ€™s-claw-extract.html whereas my desired output is  devil&#146;s-claw-extract.html. Pl help me.

Comment: @amon, Small doubt for this question... I tried this code but I got entity value as &#xE2; to this characters ’. Here I can't get values as &#x2019 to right single quote.... How can I get this value from your code...

Comment: That indicates you haven't decoded your input before using it with Perl. How do you obtain the data? Which encoding does this data have? E.g. with a file, you have to specify the encoding like `open my $fh, "<:encoding(utf8)", $filename`.

Comment: Oh k k, But, you are show output as "devil&#x2019; .... ". can you show example correctly....? plesase..

Comment: Always save your Perl source files as `UTF-8`-encoded text. Then, put `use utf8` at the top of your script to be able to use special chars inside strings etc.